# How to enforce tuple length on all function parameters that use the same generic tuple type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

It makes sense that `[number, number] | [number]` extends `[number, ...number[]]`, but I'm wondering if there's a way to enforce the tuple length based on the first parameter so that the second tuple must use that same length.

```
function addVectors<T extends [number, ...number[]]>(v1: T, v2: T) {
  // not implemented
}

// T becomes [number].
addVectors([1], [2]);

// T becomes [number, number] | [number].
addVectors([1, 3], [3]);
```

I want to prevent this from compiling:

```
addVectors([1, 3], [3]);
```

Is it possible to achieve that in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by creating a second type parameter which extends the first:

```
function addVectors<T extends [number, ...number[]], U extends T>(v1: T, v2: U) {
  // not implemented
}

// T becomes [number].
addVectors([1], [2]);

// Does not compile.
// "Argument of type '[number]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'".
addVectors([1, 3], [3]);
```

I took it a step further and made `addVectors` accept two or more vectors of the same dimension:

```
function addVectors<T extends [number, ...number[]], U extends T>(...vectors: [T, U, ...U[]]) {
  // not implemented
}

addVectors([1], [2]);

addVectors([1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]);

// Does not compile.
addVectors([1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4, 4]);
```